# Table.Properties.RowNames differs from cell array of strings

Tags: matlab

Table.Properties.RowNames seems to behave differently from a cell array of strings, even though that's apparently what it is.  I can get the behaviour of a cell array of strings by assigning it to a variable.  Wondering what the explanation for this might be...

```
>> x=array2table(ones(2),'RowNames',{'row1','row2'})
x =          Var1    Var2
            ____    ____
    row1    1       1   
    row2    1       1   

>> class(x.Properties.RowNames)
ans = cell

>> class(x.Properties.RowNames{2})
ans = char

>> x.Properties.RowNames{:} % Displays only 1st cell contents!
ans = row1

>> a=x.Properties.RowNames  % Assign to a variable
a = 'row1'
    'row2'

>> class(a)
ans = cell

>> a{:} % Displays all cells' contents
ans = row1
ans = row2
```

Comment: I'm not understanding why this is profound. What behavior do you believe is inconsistent with other cell arrays?

Comment: I wouldn't call it profound.  It's just something to watch out for.  The behaviour of x.Properties.RowNames{:} differs from that of a{:} in the original post, even they are apparently the same kind of data structure.  It means that you always have to keep in mind this exception when composing code.  You (or rather, I) can't just blindly assume that a cell array of strings behaves the same in all circumstances.  As per the answer, this requires more code and more variables -- something I try to minimize.

Comment: I was actually kind of hoping that it was a syntactical error on my part, and that an explanation would resolve the discrepancy so that an assignment to another variable would not be needed (and the need to keep in mind exceptional behaviour would be unnecessary).  Still hoping that this might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is because it's not really a cell array of strings, but a comma separated list:

```
>> x=array2table( ...
            ones(3), 'RowNames', {'Row1','RowRow2','RowRowRow3'} )
x =               Var1    Var2    Var3
                  ____    ____    ____
    Row1          1       1       1   
    RowRow2       1       1       1   
    RowRowRow3    1       1       1   

>> x.Properties.RowNames{:}
ans = Row1

>> [a,b,c]=x.Properties.RowNames{:}
a = Row1
b = RowRow2
c = RowRowRow3
```

A gotcha to watch out for is the difference in behaviour between x.Properties.RowNames{:} and a{:} for the variable "a" in the original post:

```
a=x.Properties.RowNames
```

In my particular application, this means I need to assign x.Properties.RowNames to an external variable before using a boolean vector mask to extract elements.  If I don't, then the left-hand-side of the assignment will vary in the number of output parameters depending on the boolean mask, e.g.:

```
>> [a,b]=x.Properties.RowNames{[true false true]}
a = Row1
b = RowRowRow3
```

And just as a point of edification, I found it to be an interesting reminder that even though x.Properties.RowNames is a column array of cells, the boolean vector can be horizontal or vertical (it doesn't matter).

User "excaza" reminded me that the discrepancy between

```
x.Properties.RowNames{:}
```

and

```
a=x.Properties.RowNames
a{:}
```

can be avoided by using round-bracket indexing in order to preserve cell-array-of-strings type for the data:

```
>> x.Properties.RowNames(:)
ans = 'Row1'
      'RowRow2'
      'RowRowRow3'

>> a=x.Properties.RowNames
a = 'Row1'
    'RowRow2'
    'RowRowRow3'

>> a(:)
ans = 'Row1'
      'RowRow2'
      'RowRowRow3'
```

I have to admit that I initially tried to avoid this direct solution in order to avoid the single-quote delimiters in the displayed data, but it is one way to avoid the above discrepancy with curly braces.

Comment: I could also do a straight assignment as in the original post...was hoping to avoid extra lines of code & extra variables (keep the code clean and easy to follow).  But this discovery is disturbing as it means that my shaky understanding of the difference between cell-array-of-strings versus comma-separate-list is even shakier than I thought.

Comment: @Benoit_11, `cellstr` isn't necessary

Comment: @user36800 `RowNames` isn't a comma separated list, it's a cell array. `RowNames{:}` is a comma separated list because you're extracting the data from each cell. This behavior is not inconsistent with other cell arrays.

Comment: Agreed that I'm extracting, and hence the behaviour of comma separated list.  Also agreed that it is inconsistent with the same extraction from cell array "a" in the original post (if I understood you correctly).  That's the source of my consternation.

Comment: @excaza oh shoot should have tested before posting! thanks

Comment: @user36800 regarding your edit, this is a *syntax* error. What you want is `x.Properties.RowNames([true false true])`.

Comment: Hmm, yes, you're right.  I did find beforehand that bracket indexing preserved the cell-array nature, but it also kept the single-quote delimiters, and I was trying to find alternatives. I'll modify the answer to add the bracket indexing, but I think that exposing the above behaviour with curly braces is also a good reminder for those who get confused between the two (which I often do).  Also, it's still a mystery to me why curly brace indexing would differ for the "a" variable in the original post.